# Spring boot PutMapping with Enum as RequestBody issue

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular6

I have a spring boot controller endpoint as follows.

```
@PutMapping("/manage/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> manage(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Type type) { 
  ...
}
```

Where Type is an Enum as follows.

```
public enum Type {
    ONE,
    TWO
}
```

**ISSUE 1:** When I test this controller, I have to send the content as `"ONE"` instead of `ONE` for a successful invocation. i.e. it works with the following code.

```
mvc.perform(put("/api/manage/1")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .content("\"" + Type.ONE + '\"'))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

It does not work with

```
mvc.perform(put("/api/manage/1")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .content(Type.ONE.name()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

**ISSUE 2:** I am not able to invoke this method from the Angular service.

```
this.http.put<string>('/api/manage/' + id, type)
```

gives me

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Everything works when I add the Enum to a Dto and send an object from the client. But due to some business requirements, I want to use the current structure itself. i.e the Enum as a `RequestBody`.

**UPDATE**

I also tried to change the controller method structure to

```
@PutMapping(value = "/manage/{id}", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
```

I get the following error.

> Content type 'text/plain' not supported

Comment: Were you able to find any solution? I am facing similar challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Both issues stem from trying to use a JSON endpoint as a plain text endpoint.

Ad 1, `ONE` is invalid JSON (`"ONE"` is valid)

Ad 2, when you just post a string, it is sent as `text/plain` and the endpoint complains.

Probably adding `consumes="text/plain"` to your `@PutMapping` will solve the problem, but frankly - I am not sure if string/enum mappings work out-of-the-box in the hodge-podge that is spring boot.

Comment: Actually I had added this... But I get a similar error, just that the `;charset=UTF-8` is missing. Please check the updated question